# How can I know my ssid and password for my esp8266? AT command does not work.How can I know for CWJAP username and password?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, at-command

Here is serial monitor show...

```
AT+CWJAP="AI_THINKER_F92AB1'',""
+CWJAP:1

FAIL
AT+CWSAP="AI_THINKER_F92AB1","2534",1,4

ERROR
```

What is the difference between CWJAP and CWSAP
I think CWSAP is to create and change the id and password for ESP8266 wifi and it also does not work.
I have problem with this password and id. Plz

Answer (score 0):

[The AT instruction set](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf) states that AT+CWJAP connects to an access point, while AT+CWSAP configures the ESP8266 as an access point.

Your CWJAP command returns 1, meaning that the connection has timed out, probably because there is no such access point to connect.

The CWSAP command fails because the password is too short. WPA and WPA2 encryption requires a password with minimum 8 characters.